# Gnosis safe - Module restricting certain types of transactions to certain owners?

Tags: safe-core

I am wondering if ever there is a module allowing to restrict certain types of transactions to certain owners? For instance, we would like to set up a safe where certain owners can only perform 'token swaps' but they cannot transfer funds to another address.

Many thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

There is no module allowing that specifically, but you can easily build your own by following [this guide](https://docs.safe.global/advanced/smart-account-modules). The smart contract will hold the logic for allowing only certain types of operations to certain addresses.